# Sort by distance of the words lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using `Lucene 2.9.4` in my website.
In the website there is simple a input text for the user to input text and search.

**Example:**

When the input is `Gói thầu số 15`, the`query.toString()` call returns: `(BID_NM:gói BID_NM:thầu BID_NM:số BID_NM:15)`.

The result I receive is wrong order. Instead of finding `Gói thầu số 15`, it finds the words individually, ie. `gói`,`thầu` or `số` on top result.

**My Query method:**

```
public static Query getQuery(String keyword) throws ParseException{
    try{
        return MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(Version.LUCENE_29, new     String  []{keyword}, new String[]{"NAME"}, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29));
    }catch(ParseException e){
        keyword=MultiFieldQueryParser.escape(keyword);
        return MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(Version.LUCENE_29, new String[]{keyword}, new String[]{"NAME"}, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29));
    }
}
```

**Search:**

```
IndexReader reader=null;
Query query=null;
Filter filter=null;
try{
  reader = IndexReader.open(directory, true);    // Read only
  IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
  query=getQuery(keyword);
  System.out.println(query.toString());
  TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, null, 10000, Sort.RELEVANCE);
  ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;
} catch (Exception exc) {
     exc.printStackTrace();
} finally {
      if (reader != null) {
        try {
               reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely you should use phrase search. Here, for example one of possible tutorials on the subject http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-query-for-words-near-each-other-with-a-phrase-query.html

The key point is `setSlop()` method of the `PhraseQuery` which allows to specify maximum distance between words from the query in matched documents. Also if your documents require some specific phrases to be automatically recognized during *indexing* you may find the following [tutorial](http://lucidworks.com/blog/automatic-phrase-tokenization-improving-lucene-search-precision-by-more-precise-linguistic-analysis/) useful.

Comment: Thank for answer. But I only want sort with exactly result on top

Comment: Then you should construct a boolean query, one part of which would be a PhraseQuery put into a BooleanQuery. Other BooleanQuery components are all your words as you have them right now. Thus phrase match will give you a boost but individual words will match as well.